# Slumdog millionaire (3)

Tags: geography, knowledge

My Indian friend Jamal recently participated in the well-known TV quiz
show ***[Who wants to be a millionaire?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Who_Wants_to_Be_a_Millionaire)***. You might have heard or read about Jamal's spectacular success; the media reported on it extensively.

Here is what Jamal told us about his 300 Euro question:

> After my correct answer to the second question, Prem Kumar flashed a big
>   smile at me and congratulated in an oily voice: "Youuuuuu haaaaave maaaade
>   twoooo-huuuuundred Eurooooooooo! Congratulaaaaaaations!".  I started to
>   thoroughly dislike this greasy type.  I still was somewhat nervous, as the
>   third question came up. 300 Euro for Geography, duh!
>
> I immediately discarded the last two answers; interestingly, they both
>   may be associated with the three colors that are usually associated with
>   that country.  But for answer C a rectangle, or a sheet, or a plain piece
>   of cloth would have been a much more natural choice. And for the nutrimental
>   answer D it should simply have been a circle. These two answers were too
>   contrived, perhaps intended to be humorous, and just could not be the
>   right answer, no way, not at the 300 Euro level.  Answer B would have fit
>   our beloved neighbor Sri Lanka. Hence I thought, conjectured, guessed,
>   hoped that it had to be answer A, and I decided to go for the footwear.
>
> Prem Kumar pulled off a big show, and asked twice whether this was my final
>   decision. I said Yes once, and I said Yes for a second time, and then
>   Prem said "So your decision is A." He really is not the fastest thinker.

What was the 300 Euro question?
What were the four possible answers A, B, C, D?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The 300 Euro question is:

> Like which of these items is Italy shaped?

The answers are:

> A: Boot
>  B: Teardrop
>  C: Italian Flag
>  D: Neapolitan pizza

Sri Lanka is

> shaped like a teardrop. (See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sri_Lanka#/media/File:Sri_Lanka_-_Location_Map_(2011)_-_LKA_-_UNOCHA.svg).)

C is rectangular and D is round and edible. Both contain the colours associated with the country:

> red, white, and green.

Comment: I think the question and answers A and B might be right. Not sure about C and D, especially D because it is in no way nutrimental

Comment: Good point. I knew I skipped over something.

Comment: D is probably a pizza.... not watermelon

Comment: I guess, but there's not enough information to point to a correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

The question was

> **What's the shape of Italy?**

Answers were:

> **A**: Footwear
> **B**: Lung
> **C**: Flag (Green, White, Red)
> **D**: Pizza (Green for basin, White for Mozzarella, Red for tomato)